# Почему для блока2 не работает анимация

Tags: html, css, css3

Почему для блока2 не работает анимация, блоки же соседние.
В задании указано использовать только css.
В чем проблема ?

```css
.block {
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px inset white;
}

.block1 {
    top: 80px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}

.block2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #26ff4e;
    transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
}

.block3 {
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: #ff3f36;
    transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
}

.block1:hover ~ .block2 {
    left: 0;
}

.block1:hover ~ .block3 {
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block2">block 2</div>
<div class="block block1">block 1</div>
<div class="block block3">block 3</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/wegzj5ux/

Comment: в css3 пока нет возможности напрямую влиять на левого соседа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что запись вида `.block1:hover ~ .block2` работает только для блоков, которые идут ПОСЛЕ `.block1`, вот так всё работает:

```css
.block {
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px inset white;
}

.block1 {
    top: 80px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}

.block2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #26ff4e;
    transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
}

.block3 {
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: #ff3f36;
    transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
}

.block1:hover ~ .block2 {
    left: 0;
}

.block1:hover ~ .block3 {
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">block 1</div>
<div class="block block2">block 2</div>
<div class="block block3">block 3</div>
```

Comment: не касаясь смысла вашего ответа, св-во `transition` уже давно стоит писать безо всяких префиксов.